# Need split column by comma and need to group the column in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have one table as DepartmentDoc.

```
   Name           departmentDoc    UploadCount
   -----          ----------       ---------
   Surya             IT              4
   Surya,Kavi        IT              2
   Vijay,Kavi        Sales           2
   Vijay,Surya,Kavi  Purchase        1
   Swathi            Purchase        2
```

I want to split the string which contains ',' then I need to group the names. My out put select query will do the following actions,

1)Need to spilt Name column value which contains ','
2)After splitted the text we need to seggregate the names with new rows and provide the same upload count for all users individually.

My output should be,

```
   Name           departmentDoc    UploadCount
   -----          ----------       ---------
   Surya             IT              4
   Surya             IT              2
   Kavi              IT              2
   Vijay             Sales           2
   Kavi              Sales           2
   Vijay             Purchase        1
   Surya             Purchase        1
   Kavi              Purchase        1
   Swathi            Purchase        2
```

I don't know how to spilt the comma added text and make a new row for splitted text in SQL server. Please help me on this.Thanks.

Comment: You should never store multiple values in a single field. That will always cause you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    ( Name  varchar(16),  departmentDoc  varchar(8),  UploadCount  int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ( Name ,  departmentDoc ,  UploadCount )
VALUES
    ('Surya', 'IT', 4),
    ('Surya,Kavi', 'IT', 2),
    ('Vijay,Kavi', 'Sales', 2),
    ('Vijay,Surya,Kavi', 'Purchase', 1),
    ('Swathi', 'Purchase', 2)
;


;with cte as (
SELECT   
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Name  ,departmentDoc, UploadCount
 FROM  (SELECT   
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([Name], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String ,departmentDoc, UploadCount
     FROM  @Table1) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))


select * from CTE
```

Comment: Excellent.This method is working for me. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: thank you so much & WC @Suryakavitha

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    departmentDoc VARCHAR(20),
    UploadCount INT
)

INSERT INTO @t (Name, departmentDoc, UploadCount)
VALUES
    ('Surya' , 'IT', 4),
    ('Surya,Kavi' , 'IT', 2),
    ('Vijay,Kavi ' , 'Sales', 2),
    ('Vijay,Surya,Kavi' , 'Purchase', 1),
    ('Swathi' , 'Purchase', 2)

SELECT O.Name,
       t.departmentDoc,
       t.UploadCount
FROM (
    SELECT *, x = CAST('<X>' + REPLACE(Name, ',', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML)
    FROM @t
) t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT Name = t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    FROM x.nodes('X') t(c)
) O
```

output -

```
Name         departmentDoc        UploadCount
------------ -------------------- -----------
Surya        IT                   4
Surya        IT                   2
Kavi         IT                   2
Vijay        Sales                2
Kavi         Sales                2
Vijay        Purchase             1
Surya        Purchase             1
Kavi         Purchase             1
Swathi       Purchase             2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a string splitting function, like the [DelimitedSplait8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden. That way you don't have to worry about having anything that could break the XML functions in your data.

Example:

```
select
S.Item,
T.departmentDoc,
T.UploadCount
from table1 T
cross apply DelimitedSplit8K(Name, ',') S
```

Your example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/426160/1)